# Left shift using bitwise AND

Tags: c

The following lines of code Shift left 5 bits ie make bottom 3 bits the 3 MSB's

```
 DWORD dwControlLocAddress2;
 DWORD dwWriteDataWordAddress //Assume some initial value
 dwControlLocAddress2 = ((dwWriteDataWordAddress & '\x07') * 32);
```

Can somebody help me understand how?

Comment: 2^5 = 32, multiplying by 2^n shifts n bits in binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by a power of two *x* is the same as left shifting by *log<sub>2</sub>(x)*:

```
  x *= 2   ->    x <<= 1
  x *= 4   ->    x <<= 2
     .
     .
     .
  x *= 32  ->    x <<= 5
```

The `&` doesn't do the shift - it just masks the bottom three bits.  The syntax used in your example is a bit weird - it's using a hexadecimal character literal `'\x07'`, but that's literally identical to hex `0x07`, which in turn in binary is:

```
  00000111
```

Since any bit ANDed with `0` yields `0` and any bit ANDed with `1` is itself, the `&` operation in your example simply gives a result of being the bottom three bits of `dwWriteDataWordAddress`.

Answer (score 5):

The `0x07` is 00000111 in binary. So you are masking the input value and getting just the right three bits. Then you are multiplying by 32 which is 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2... which, if you think about it, shifting left by 1 is the same as multiplying by 2. So, shifting left five times is the same as multiplying by 32.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit obtuse but essentially you're anding with `0x07` and then multiplying by `32` which is the same as shifting by `5`. I'm not sure why a character literal is used rather than an integer literal but perhaps so that it is represented as a single byte rather than a word.

The equivalent would be:

```
( ( dw & 0x07 ) << 5 )
```

The `& 0x07` masks off the first 3 bits and `<< 5` does a left shift by 5 bits.

Answer (score 1):

`& '\x07'` - masks in the bottom three bits only (hex 7 is 111 in binary)

`* 32` - left shifts by 5 (32 is 2^5)